# How can I delete records based on a query?

Tags: sql, vba

What I am trying to accomplish is to have VBA run the delete query on backup. The issue is with my query (I hope)
I have a select query that isolates records which I want to delete, however when I try to make it a delete query I get this error:

> Specify the table containing the records you want to delete.

OR this error:

> Reserved error (-3211); there is no message for this error.

My select statement reads:

```
SELECT Manhours.*, Tickets.Status, Year([Open Date])
FROM Manhours INNER JOIN Tickts ON Manhours.TicketID = Tickets.ID
WHERE (Tickets.Status) = "Closed" AND ((Year([Open Date]))< Year(DATE())-1 
      OR ((Year([Open Date]))= Year(DATE()-1))
```

The select statement will call the records I need, but when I try to make it a delete query it errors out.

Comment: You can only delete rows from one tablet at a time. You are specifying two tables in your select clause. What should be deleted?

Comment: Both tables data will be deleted eventually. I am assuming I can only delete data from one table at a time. In this example the manhours table is having records deleted as they relate to the Tickets table. The criteria from the Tickets table is what determines which manhours record should be deleted (Manhours.TicketID = Ticket.ID). I've been looking for a method to do this so if there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

I found what I was looking for:

`DELETE FROM Manhours
 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Tickets
 WHERE (Tickets.Status) = "Closed" 
 AND ((Year([Open Date]))< Year(DATE())-1 OR ((Year([Open Date]))= Year(DATE()-1))`